# Finding the basis from a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a question about how I can find the basis of a subspace given a span.

$$\text{Let W be the subspace of $\mathrm{R}^4$ spanned by the set {(1, 2, 0, 2),(−2, −5, 5, 6),(0, −3, 15, 18),(0, −2, 10, 8)}}$$

I created my matrix and put it into REF:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 2\\\ 
-2 & -5  & 5  & 6 \\\ 
0 & -3  & 15  & 18 \\\ 
0 & -2  & 10  & 8
\end{bmatrix}$$ $$\downarrow$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 0 & 2\\\ 
0 & 1  & 5  & 10 \\\ 
0 & 0  & 0  & -12 \\\ 
0 & 0  & 0  & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm confused how I can find the basis for W. I am aware of how to find the basis for the row space, column space and null space, but the wording of just W is throwing me off somewhat.

Comment: i think that the  $a_{11}$ place in the matrix should be -1 instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Row reduction operations don't change the row space. So for each operation you performed on your matrix, you maintained the invariant that $W$ is your row space. So the usual technique for obtaining a basis for your row space corresponds to a basis for $W$. That is, we can read off the first three rows of the row echelon form to obtain a basis using only three vectors instead of the initial four.